# which API should i use so as to access the V2beta2PodsMetricStatus Model of kubernetes-client in Python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, metrics

I am developing an application in python where i need to consume the current values of a metric for some pods(eg. cpu, memory). I can get this info through an API (/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods) but i try to use the kubernetes client so as to access these metrics within my python app.

I see that the [V2beta2PodsMetricStatus](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V2beta2PodsMetricStatus.md) Model includes the information i need but i can not find the [API endpoint](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes#documentation-for-api-endpoints) i should use so as to reach this model.

Any help or alternative option would be very helpful since i am really stacked with this issue several days.

Thank you very much for you time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get the metrics by executing directly the relevant kubectl command. I do not like the solution but it works. Hope to be able to use the kubernetes-client instead at the near future.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.getoutput('kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods')
ret_metrics = json.loads(p)
items = ret_metrics['items']
 for item in items:
   print(item['metadata']['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `call_api method` of `api_client` as below to call an API which is not part of core kubernetes API.

```
ret_metrics = api_client.call_api('/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods', 'GET', auth_settings = ['BearerToken'], response_type='json', _preload_content=False) 
response = ret_metrics[0].data.decode('utf-8')
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1247) to support it via `V2beta2PodsMetricStatus` model

Comment: i opened that issue :-) . Seems that the call_api will be soon obsolete. Apart from this the call_api is not stable. sometimes it returns the metrics, but most of the time i get a kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (404)

Comment: I do not understand why some times i get the metrics through the api_client and after while i get the '404 Not Found' response. The result is the same. how i can get the metrics i need?